# Better alternative to standard windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative Windows command shell and console?](https://superuser.com/questions/87441/alternative-windows-command-shell-and-console)

Is there an alternative to the standard windows command (cmd.exe) prompt?

It is sometimes difficult reading debug data, I'm curious to know if there are any alternatives that could offer tabbed windows etc.

Comment: `cmd.exe` is a _command shell_, it only handles command input. The interface (tabs, toolbars, etc) would be part of a _terminal_ program (such as Console).

Comment: @Nelson - I just flagged it as a dup, so a mod can close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

> Console is a Windows console window
>   enhancement. Console features include:
>   multiple tabs, text editor-like text
>   selection, different background types,
>   alpha and color-key transparency,
>   configurable font, different window
>   styles.